# Converting CorelDraw Files to Adobe In-Design CS6 Files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, vector, cs6, corel-draw

I am new to doing vector graphics and am currently facing the following issue. I have several (20-30) files created in CorelDraw X7 17.3 that need to be converted to Adobe In-Design. The reason for this is that I am much more familiar with Adobe products and feel much more at-home with them. CorelDraw feels clunky and unknown.

Hence, I am wondering what is the most efficient way of doing this. Do I have to manually re-create each design or is there a better method?

Comment: This is not clear at all. Do you have a vector graphic or you have a layout with long text? What kind of design is it? What is that you need to modify? What is the clunky part? What is "Design" for you? Probably showing an image of your "design"would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Corel has some layout tools that probably put it in between of Illustrator and InDesign, so, without seeing what you mean by "design" it is hard to know.

If it is a Vector Image, an illustration, you can probably just save it as AI inside Corel. Version X7 can export to AI natively to CS6. This way you will preserve layers, that is an important way of keeping things organized and editable.

You can also export images as raster TIF, PNG, JPG, PSD or any format you need.

---

But again, it depends on what is in the file, and what you need to modify if you need to modify it.

Corel is not a clunky at all. It is a pretty solid application. If it is unknown to you that is a separated issue.

---

Depending on what you need to modify you could probably learn a couple of tools to do your job. A lot of times it is a lot better to leave a file in its native format. Not all "effects" can be exported if you need to adjust them. Normally they need to be "fixed" for example rasterizing them.

---

If your "design" is, in reality, a layout template... Just do that from scratch in InDesign. You can probably just export a raster image from Corel and use it as a base to construct your grid.

The reason of this is that in InDesign you need to construct a solid foundation with your master pages and styles.

Corel Draw has its own styling system but you can not export it to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

InDesign is more of a layout tool than Draw.

A more accurate conversion would from CorelDraw to Adobe Illustrator.

In which case, save the Corel files as EPS... and then open the EPS with Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

This worked in another software, let's call that software =X. Try the same with CDR. Skip this, if your files are complex compositions, for example scripted worksheets. This can work only with graphic images with simple typography.

**The problem**: No apparent way to transfer a vector file from X to Illustrator as an editable vector drawing. All exports are bitmap images or totally unopenable in Illustrator.

**The solution**: I printed the image in X as PDF. The printer was Adobe PDF. That PDF was fully editable in Illustrator. The paths were not splintered unusable and nothing were transformed to a bitmap.

It surely was a an accident that Adobe PDF was by default set properly for this. Generally the more a PDF is compressed, the less editable it will be in Illustrator.